# Getting http2 exception on a Flink Job with a GCP PubSub source

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a flink job that uses GCP PubSub as the source. Even though I'm able to process messages I receive on a pubsub topic, I see a couple of problems with it:

1. The message that was processed earlier shows up again (Indication that acknowledgement wasn't made)
2. I see grpc http2 exceptions on my flink job along with the checkpoint logs

Exception stack trace:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.acknowledge(SubscriberGrpc.java:1628)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.acknowledge(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.common.AcknowledgeOnCheckpoint.notifyCheckpointComplete(AcknowledgeOnCheckpoint.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource.notifyCheckpointComplete(PubSubSource.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.notifyCheckpointComplete(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.notifyCheckpointComplete(SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamTask.java:1092)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$notifyCheckpointCompleteAsync$11(StreamTask.java:1057)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$notifyCheckpointOperation$13(StreamTask.java:1080)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:317)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:189)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:619)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:583)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:758)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Header size exceeded max allowed size (10240)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:103)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2CodecUtil.headerListSizeExceeded(Http2CodecUtil.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$HeadersBlockBuilder.headerSizeExceeded(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:694)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$HeadersBlockBuilder.addFragment(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:710)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$2.processFragment(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:481)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readHeadersFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:491)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:254)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:174)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:378)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1526)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1275)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1322)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
```

The below seem to be the underlying cause

```
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Header size exceeded max allowed size (10240)
```

Here's how I configured my PubSubSource object:

```
    PubSubSource pubSubSource =
        PubSubSource.newBuilder()
            .withDeserializationSchema(new SomeDeserializer())
            .withProjectName("some-project")
            .withSubscriptionName("some-subscription")
            .withCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(file))
            .withPubSubSubscriberFactory(100, Duration.ofSeconds(90), 3)
            .build();
```

Checkpointing interval is 60s (lesser than the ack deadline)

What could be the cause for the above 2 issues ?

Comment: It seems like the issue is related to the Java library. Can you  take a look at these errors: [error1](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/8919) and [error2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2935), as well as [link3](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#maxInboundMetadataSize-int-)? Let me know if this information is helpful or not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'd gone through these earlier and had increased the `maxInboundMetadataSize(20480)` by implementing a custom class that implements `PubSubSubscriberFactory` but I got an exception saying the size increased to 25600 or something. I'd want to understand if it is correct to increase the header size or is this some issue with the setup.

Answer (score 1):

I increased the `maxInboundMetadataSize` further to 1MB and then it started to work.

```
public class CustomPubSubSubscriberFactory implements PubSubSubscriberFactory {
  private final int retries;
  private final Duration timeout;
  private final int maxMessagesPerPull;
  private final String projectSubscriptionName;

  public CustomPubSubSubscriberFactory(
      String projectSubscriptionName, int retries, Duration pullTimeout, int maxMessagesPerPull) {
    this.retries = retries;
    this.timeout = pullTimeout;
    this.maxMessagesPerPull = maxMessagesPerPull;
    this.projectSubscriptionName = projectSubscriptionName;
  }

  @Override
  public PubSubSubscriber getSubscriber(Credentials credentials) throws IOException {
    ManagedChannel channel =
        NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget(SubscriberStubSettings.getDefaultEndpoint())
            .negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS)
            .sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forClient().ciphers(null).build())
            .maxInboundMetadataSize(1048576)
            .build();

    PullRequest pullRequest =
        PullRequest.newBuilder()
            .setMaxMessages(maxMessagesPerPull)
            .setSubscription(projectSubscriptionName)
            .build();
    SubscriberGrpc.SubscriberBlockingStub stub =
        SubscriberGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
            .withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(credentials));
    return new BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber(
        projectSubscriptionName, channel, stub, pullRequest, retries, timeout);
  }
}
```

Invoked as

```
PubSubSource pubSubSource =
        PubSubSource.newBuilder()
            .withDeserializationSchema(new SomeDeserializer())
            .withProjectName("some-project")
            .withSubscriptionName("some-subscription")
            .withCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(file))
            .withPubSubSubscriberFactory(
                new CustomPubSubSubscriberFactory(
                    ProjectSubscriptionName.format(
                        "some-project", "some-subscription"),
                    3,
                    Duration.ofSeconds(90),
                    100))            
            .build();
```